# Dropbox can't be started

Tags: permissions, users, dropbox, accounts

I can't startup Dropbox and reinstalling Dropbox won't work either. It states it could be a permission issue on startup. The generated error log states this:

```
bn.BUILD_KEY: Dropbox
bn.VERSION: 12.4.22
bn.DROPBOXEXT_VERSION: failed
bn.is_frozen: True
pid: 2701
ppid: 2698
ppid exe: '/usr/bin/python2.7'
uid: 1000
user_info: pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='edge', pw_passwd='x', pw_uid=1000, pw_gid=1000, pw_gecos='edge,,,', pw_dir='/home/edge', pw_shell='/bin/bash')
effective_user_info: pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='edge', pw_passwd='x', pw_uid=1000, pw_gid=1000, pw_gecos='edge,,,', pw_dir='/home/edge', pw_shell='/bin/bash')
euid: 1000
gid: 1000
egid: 1000
group_info: grp.struct_group(gr_name='edge', gr_passwd='x', gr_gid=1000, gr_mem=[])
effective_group_info: grp.struct_group(gr_name='edge', gr_passwd='x', gr_gid=1000, gr_mem=[])
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: None
cwd: '/home/edge'
     real_path='/home/edge'
            mode=040700 uid=1000    gid=1000
     parent mode=040755 uid=0   gid=0
HOME: u'/home/edge'
appdata: u'/home/empedokles/.dropbox/instance1'
         real_path=u'/home/empedokles/.dropbox/instance1'
                not found
         parent not found
dropbox_path: u'/home/empedokles/Dropbox'
              real_path=u'/home/empedokles/Dropbox'
                        not found
              parent    not found
sys_executable: '/home/edge/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-12.4.22/dropbox'
                real_path='/home/edge/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-12.4.22/dropbox'
                        mode=0100755    uid=1000    gid=1000
                parent  mode=040755 uid=1000    gid=1000
trace.__file__: '/home/edge/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-12.4.22/library.zip/dropbox/client/ui/common/boot_error.pyc'
                real_path='/home/edge/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-12.4.22/library.zip/dropbox/client/ui/common/boot_error.pyc'
                        not found
                parent  not found
tempdir: '/tmp'
         real_path='/tmp'
                mode=041777 uid=0   gid=0
         parent mode=040755 uid=0   gid=0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dropbox/client/main.py", line 5412, in main_startup
  File "dropbox/client/main.py", line 2046, in run
  File "dropbox/client/main.py", line 1149, in startup_low
  File "dropbox/client/main.py", line 835, in safe_makedirs
  File "os.py", line 150, in makedirs
  File "os.py", line 150, in makedirs
  File "os.py", line 157, in makedirs
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/empedokles'
```

It still links to my old user folder (I did change my user name). How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you changed your username, you need to uninstall Dropbox and remove the .dropbox* directories under your `$HOME` and than, reinstall Dropbox again.

It's can be done by open Terminal and:

**Remove dropbox:**

```
sudo apt-get remove dropbox
```

**Delete dropbox hidden directories:**

```
rm -rvf ~/.dropbox ~/.dropbox-dist
```

Now you can [install dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux)